# EnforceConstraints Problem

Tags: c#, dataset

dsrm_usersTableAdapters.rm_usersIPTableAdapter _tuser = new dsrm_usersTableAdapters.rm_usersIPTableAdapter();

```
dsrm_users _dsuser = new dsrm_users();
_dsuser.EnforceConstraints = false;

dsrm_users.rm_usersIPDataTable _muser = _dsuser.rm_usersIP;
_tuser.FillBy(_muser, _IP);
```

it is very good works;

However, when I use ObjectDataSource and connect to grid view using GetData() method, it gives an error;

Failed to enable constraints. One or more rows contain values violating non-null, unique, or foreign-key constraints Error;

I go to the Dataset and  I set EnforceConstraints=false in Property Window , and I try agin its give again same erorr. So EnforceConstraints=false does not work with GetDATA();

So what can I do now? How can I use ObjectDataSource using GetData() without this error.

Answer (score 1):

I would first try and determine why your constraints are failing.

You can determine this by

```
_dsuser.EnforceConstraints = false;
//fill info
try
{
    _dsuser.EnforceConstraints = true;
}
catch
{
            if (ds.HasErrors)
            {
                DataRow[] drs = _dsuser.[datatablename].GetErrors();
                foreach(DataRow dr in drs)
                {
                    foreach(DataColumn dc in dr.GetColumnsInError())
                    {
                        Console.Write(dr.GetColumnError(dc));
                    }
                }
            }
}
```

This will print to the console any errors in the datatable

You can also loop thru' the tables with ds.tables if you do not know the table name.